# Regex to match all strings, strings with dots in between, and does not match strings with dash in between

Tags: regex, string, url-routing, pcre

I am trying to create a URL Routing rule for restful `API`.

I need a `Regex` that follows three simple rules:

1. Match all strings
2. Match strings with dots in between like android package names: `com.test.package`
3. Does not match strings with dashes in between like: `test-health`

I've tried this rule it matches everything except android package name like strings. here is the rule:

```
<id:\\w+[.+]?>
```

P.S: I am using this `Regex` in Url Routing of `Yii2 Framework` which handles `^` and `$` as the beginning and the ending of the Regex strings internally so I had to omit those.

Comment: Something like `^\w+(?:\.\w+)*$`?

Comment: @revo  Yeah, thank you so much. this works fine. you might as well answer it so that others can use it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in building your character class where you added `+` in it. I assume you were trying to apply a quantifier but it doesn't work inside a character class. `[.+]?` means either a period or a literal `+` or nothing at all.

So if you remove that `+` your regular expression is close to work `\w+\.?`. But yet it doesn't match all consecutive occurrences of words and periods e.g. `word.word.word` and you have to quantify whole expression as well: `(?:\w+\.?)+`

The regex which fits your need at the most would be `^\w+(?:\.\w+)*$`